# YAGPDB Discord Bot - Custom command to limit reaction

Tags: discord

I am trying to create a voting channel where the YAGPDB bot will automatically react "" and "" to every message posted in that particular channel. And people will be able to react only one of them. Can someone advise on how to do it?

I was able to write the code this far:

```
{{addMessageReactions nil $.Message.ID ":thumbsup:" ":thumbsdown:"}}
```

Comment: What libary you using?

Comment: I am using regex from the YAGPDB control panel.

Answer (score 0):

On the Role Command category under Role Commands, just set it to Mode: Single
[image]